# Subscription API Error 400 Unable to reach callback URL

Tags: instagram-api

I've made subscriptions with Instagram before with their public API and it has worked fine, as of recently I stopped getting calls from them at my callback for the subscription.  As of now I deleted all of my subscriptions and tried to make a new one, but keep getting an Error 400 Unable to reach callback URL my.url.com.  My callback URL is public and I've tried other sites that are public and I keep getting the same error.  I've submitted an error report to Instagram, but have not heard back in a couple days.  Any ideas on what to do next or is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: I think the API changed. Mine's been broken for about a month now. Looking into it.

Comment: Hi all, any luck getting your callback URL to work? I've posted the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993689/instagram-subscription-unable-to-reach-callback-url-ongoing

Comment: @Francesco nope, still get the same error.  I haven't heard from Instagram in over a month and just used a slightly less elegant approach.  Best of luck!