# Instagram subscription - Unable to reach callback URL - ONGOING

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

This issue has been posted many times before but I haven't found a solution yet. I've contacted Instagram Developer support but a week later I've still had no luck or a response form them so hoping someone here can help me out. My app has been approved by Instagram for basic permissions.

Doing a Form POST to https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/ with all the relevant data (callback_url, object=user, aspect=media, verify_token, client_secret, client_id) to create a subscription for Instagram User Subscriptions yields the error: APISubscriptionError - Unable to reach callback URL

- The callback URL I'm using has logging on it to log all requests which works
  when accessed directly via a browser. Using the logs I can see Instagram isn't even reached my callback URL.
- The callback URL is accessible publicly over the internet and the domain is being used in production.
- The callback URL implements both GET and POST methods (even PUT just in case).
- Worked a few weeks ago using a UAT URL.
- The callback URL still returns the 'Unable to reach callback URL' with http or https.
- I've changed IP addresses, used a VPN and run the post script form different locations.
- Tried different parts eg domain.com/instagram/subscriptions or
  domain.com/instagramsubscriptions
  -Tried a different sub domain and different URL.
- Have deleted all subscriptions using the DELETE request

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.  Tried hosting my webhook in several different places (EC2, AWS Lambda, ngrok), no luck. No answer from instagram support. :(

Comment: Hi Keeth. I've tried Azure hosting and also SNI SSL and IP Based SSL... absolutely nothing is working. I would never wish this on anyone but in a way it's good to know it's happening to someone else. Now I know it's not just me. I've tried to get my contacts at Facebook to help out but all they do it point me back to Instagram support who don't reply. I'm starting to think maybe Instagram IT are in some kind of code freeze and that's what they don't reply. Here's hoping this gets resolved soon.

Comment: Yes I've also contacted IG twice via dev support and once via Twitter, no reply. I had my app approved the other day so their dev relations team cannot be totally dead. Maybe they are planning to phase out subscriptions.  I'm looking at doing some kind of polling instead, which is more effort and scales badly :(

Comment: I'm going to go for a polling solution as well in the mean time. Are you by any chance using cloudflare as your DNS provider? Just wondering if perhaps this has an influence on Instagram not being able to reach my domain.

Comment: Same issue here. :/

Comment: Francesco no not using CloudFlare.  I'm all AWS.

Comment: I've also tried bypassing Instagrams load balancer in case I was connecting to a dudd server by connecting directly to the api servers via their IP address:

#31.13.76.84 api.instagram.com
#31.13.69.245 api.instagram.com
#31.13.77.52 api.instagram.com
#179.60.192.52 api.instagram.com
#31.13.65.52 api.instagram.com
#31.13.95.48 api.instagram.com

None of these have worked either ;(

Comment: Same problem, tried on Azure with a custom app that as a side effect logs all requests and indeed there is none. Of course POST/GET requests issued by browser, curl, ... work fine, so the issue seems to be purely on Instagram part, before the request is sent (or reaches my endpoint).

Comment: Same issue here, a month later. I've tried pretty much everything you've tried.

Comment: I read an answer to another similar question that suggested using IPv6 and an AAAA record. Has anyone tried this?

Comment: @TimFletcher I just tried it this morning and it's working for me. Hopefully it's now working for you too :-)

Comment: It is working for us again without changing any server configuration.

Comment: @Francesco Thanks for the heads-up. It's working here too. :)